# Http 404: Not Found (WebException)

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am using a console app/class library to invoke a asp.net web service. The class library queries the database and sends the data to the web service. What I notice is that when the amount of data is huge (with 20 columns and 18K records), i get a HTTP 404: Not Found exception from the web service.

I have tried increasing the maxReqeustLength and executionTimeout properties in the httpRuntime tag in the web.config of the web service.

Is there any thing that I can do to overcome this?

Thanks,
Rajeev

Comment: Windows Server 2003. ASP.NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

404 indicates that the file is not found.  You're going to have to look closer into the data to see if there is a misspelling somewhere or possibly an incorrect path to your file.  It has nothing to do with timeouts or request lengths.

Comment: Thanks, but the funny thing is when I add filters and reduce the amount of data, everything works perfect. No complaints.

Comment: Then possibly there is a corrupted record that when it's filtered out, everything works fine?

Comment: That could be a possibility. I will try that option. Let me see. Thanks for that...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have custom error pages configured? It might have been a server-side error which causes a redirect to a pre-configured error page which doesn't exist?